# Is BB-8 female?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, droids, bb-8

I don’t remember where I saw it, but I read somewhere that BB-8 is supposed to be female (s/he has a different “voice” than R2, at least).

Is there any evidence supporting either gender for BB-8?

Comment: It's a rolling ball that speaks in beeps and boops.

Comment: Is R2-D2 a male? What gender is C-3P0? Is my iPhone a male/female?

Comment: @Mooz [Droids can have gender](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7731/is-a-droid-a-he-she-or-an-it).

Comment: Well C-3PO is definitely male voiced.

Comment: Well *I'm* just a [Freak](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7380/21267), what would I know?

Comment: @JakeGould - because JJAbrams didn't brag about it NOT being one yet.

Comment: I think all droids are gluten free...

Comment: @JakeGould stop triggering me :( :

Comment: Done. According to novelization, it's a "he". Please see the update (and accept if it seems good)

Comment: @JakeGould: droids are definitely made in facilities that process nuts (and bolts, and rivets).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### In-universe UPDATED. TL;DR: The most canonical is that he's male.

- There is no gender clearly specified in the film to my recollection *(this part is subject to review as I re-watch, or as official script is available)*.
- **BB-8 is referred to as "he" in the Alan Dean Foster novelization, so the answer is "not female"**.

  Except that sometimes it's an ungendered "it" too.

  > Where a human would see only empty night sky, advanced calibrated synthetic optics saw a moving point of light. When the light resolved itself into four separate points, the droid commenced an agitated beeping. The phenomenon **he** was seeing might signify nothing, except…
  >
  > Beeping and whistling in something approaching cybernetic panic, the droid spun and sped back toward the village. That is, **its** head spun... While **it** could have transmitted the conclusion it had reached, **it** did not do so for fear of any such message being intercepted
  >
  > So BB-8 was forced to dodge and avoid, which **he** did with skill and patience,...
  >
  > Deep within the village, there was far less likelihood of encountering anything domesticated that was worth eating: a biological process **he** understood from an objective point of view but for which **he** could never rouse much empathy. **His** goal was close, and there was not a nanosecond to lose.
  >
  > ...Far away now, a solitary spherical droid looked back even as **it** continued to flee. The fireball that rose into the sky suggested the detonation of something far more volatile than primitive buildings and scrapped mechanicals. If **he** could have rolled faster, the frightened droid would have done so.
  > ...  There were things in the vacant, wild regions of underdeveloped planets that would gladly take apart a solitary droid just to see what made it tick. Or roll, **he** knew. **His** internal gyros threatened to send him tumbling wildly at the very thought of such an encounter.
  > Droids such as **him** were not meant for unpopulated places, and he desperately desired to find others like himself. Or, failing that, even people.
- No gendered info in Pablo Hidalgo's Visual Dictionary page for BB-8.

### Out of Universe:

As the Facebook status goes, "it's complicated".

- On one hand, JJ Abrams [was reputed to say](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/star-wars-the-force-awakens/bb-8-droid-girl-female/):

  > JJ [Abrams] was determined to make BB-8 cute and strong – and female.  They want to appeal to girls as much boys, who have traditionally been the fan base. She’s going to be one of the breakout hits of the film.”

  Same source says:

  > Lucasfilm president Kathleen Kennedy later referred to BB-8 as “she”, and reports from the films set, as well as some of the Star Wars publicity materials, suggested that the new droid was a girl (confusingly, puppeteers Dave Chapman and Brian Herring, who are responsible for operating the robot, have previously referred to BB-8 as “him”).
- However, same JJAbrams called BB-8 a "he" in [Entertainment Weekly](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/08/12/star-wars-force-awakens-character-names/4).

  > Abrams chose the droid’s name because it looked round and bouncy. “I named **him** BB-8 because it was almost onomatopoeia,” the director says. “It was sort of how he looked to me, with the 8, obviously, and then the 2 B’s.”
- All the acting "talent" behind BB-8 was male:

  > Dave Chapman and Brian Herring served as puppeteers for BB-8,[36] with Bill Hader and Ben Schwartz credited as "Vocal Consultants"[37]. ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens), citing [SW.com news](http://www.starwars.com/news/droid-dreams-how-neal-scanlan-and-the-star-wars-the-force-awakens-team-brought-bb-8-to-life) and [HitFlix](http://www.hitfix.com/motion-captured/wait-a-minute-who-played-the-voice-of-bb-8-in-star-wars-the-force-awakens))

  However, from what I could tell from Ben Schwartz's interviews, most of the "talent" came out of iPad app, which again supports "no gender" status as iPads aren't gendered.

(@rand's answer has more complete details of the "complicated" status :)

Comment: Sorry, I ninja'd you this time :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I got all the same quotes you did, more quickly, and I definitely got them independently :-) You did beat me on in-universe, if a lack of info counts as better than a complete lack of info!

Comment: Yep, I edited in the bit about acting talent shortly before you did - jinx!

Comment: Let the vote wars commence, I guess? ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor - you're winning 2/1 so far, as far as I can see. I'm repcapped so hard to track :( May the evens ever be in your favor!

Comment: Yikes, someone reversed their UV on mine :-( Good job on the repcap - so early too! Any idea what ridiculous rep figure you 'should' have got this week if not for the cap?

Comment: Clearly BB-8 is the strong female role in the movie.

Comment: “It was sort of how he looked to me, with the 8, obviously, and then the 2 B’s.” Perhaps the Bouba/Kiki effect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect

Comment: IIRC, Rey refers to BB-8 as a 'he' at least once in the film

Comment: Grr, I see you got the tick on this one :-)

Comment: @randal'thor -  check out the rep for today :) ALso, you can't complain, I upvoted you so I did all I could :)

Comment: @DVK Congrats on beating Richard's record for most rep earned in 1 day!

Comment: @randal'thor - in all fairness, I only did because Richard was the one who awarded me a large bounty (which I did earn fair and square, but  he ddn't have to offer it). Still no bounty hat though :(

Comment: @DVK I think Edward Edwards is for your *first* bounty on a site, or something like that. Maybe try to earn one at Lifehacks along with your Explorer? ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor -  if only peopls stopped asking TFA questions here for a day :(

Comment: @DVK Oh, if only. The site is *swamped* with SW questions. Need more WoT or HP or DW!

Comment: @randal'thor - get SE to raise the repcap. I have many HP ones saved up :)

Comment: @DVK Raise it to about 1000 per day? ;-) I'd love to, but I think we'd get a big fat [status-declined] slapped on...

Comment: Listed as male in the Junior novel: *Rey put the ship on autopilot and checked on BB-8. The wild ride had pitched the little droid around the cockpit like a kernpop in a kettle. **He beeped that he would need 1.3 standard minutes to calibrate his servos.*** and Star Wars: Before the Awakening - "*BB-8 burbled again, less communicating **than talking to himself,"***

Answer (score 17):

### Unclear, but probably male.

[This quote](http://www.slashfilm.com/bb-8-gender/) (published on 13 November 2015) from Neal Scanlan, the head of the *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* creature shop, sums up the confusion rather nicely:

> **I’m still not sure**, dare I say, whether BB-8 is male or female. BB-8 **was female in our eyes. And then she became male**. And that’s all part of the evolution, not only visually, but in the way they move, how they hold themselves.

---

**The case for female**

An anonymous "source close to the film makers" [said](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/star-wars-the-force-awakens/bb-8-droid-girl-female/):

> There’s never been a strong female robot in any Star Wars film. [JJ Abrams] was determined to make BB-8 cute and strong – **and female**.  They want to appeal to girls as much boys, who have traditionally been the fan base. She’s going to be one of the breakout hits of the film.

According to the same article, published 2 November 2015, Lucasfilm president Kathleen Kennedy also referred to BB-8 as "she".

---

**The case for male**

JJ Abrams referred to BB-8 as male in [an interview](http://www.wired.com/?p=1922154#slide-3) published in December 2015:

> Yes, BB-8 is a great character, amazingly puppeteered, but what will happen when **he’s** suddenly in a scene with C-3P0 or R2-D2? Will it feel bizarre? Will it feel wrong? Somehow it didn’t.

Brian Herring, one of the puppeteers running BB-8, also [referred to him](http://www.starwars.com/news/droid-dreams-how-neal-scanlan-and-the-star-wars-the-force-awakens-team-brought-bb-8-to-life) as male (published 26 August 2015):

> BB-8 can cock **his** head over and look away, **he** can double take, he can look scared, he can look angry. We managed to find a whole vocabulary of movement for him, if you will. We worked out a whole bunch of stuff. What would he do if you turned him off? What happens to his head if you power him down? Does he go down stairs? Does he go up stairs?

It's possibly worth noting that the puppeteers who run BB-8, Brian Herring and Dave Chapman, are both male. So in that sense the droid is 'played' by men.

Comment: You may be able to add some information based on who performed the beeps. IIRC they were male actors.

Comment: So... At one point, but not during the movie?

Comment: Also people made the beeps, not a computer?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai BB-8's voice was performed by comedians Bill Hader and Ben Schwartz, but their whirs and bloops were probably subject to some post-production processing

Comment: @RyanVeeder - iPad app, I think. But it was kinda confusing so I may have misunderstood their statements

Comment: Give us some dates, for the interviews, it helps the reader know when bb-8 was Female, and when the mind set for male shifted. :D

Comment: @Himarm Good point; dates added. The Scanlan quote seems to be the most recent, as I thought.

Comment: Ninja-ed you right back with novelization cites

Comment: @DVK Good job! :-) I would upvote you, but there's not much point at the moment as you're repcapping so well. I'll come back to upvote if your rep gains ever go back to mortal levels...

Comment: @randal'thor - there's always bounties *\*hopefully looking like a cutest ever Ewok\**

Comment: @DVK A guy who can get 427 rep in a day don't *need* no bounties :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - he still leads me in rankings by a wide margin

Comment: @DVK "he"? Are you referring to your nemesis, he of the junior novelisations and gold tag badges? You're top of all but the quarterly and yearly leagues, which will soon change anyway.

Comment: @randal'thor - yes and no, respectively. I accidentally had a week of vacation right as TFA came out (**I am dead serious. I had no idea of the timing when I scheduled the week**. Luck!), so I was able to overindulge in both consuming canon and producing tons of (hopefully) quality posts. However, I'm unable - and franky, not too tempted - to sustain Richard's rates of posting long term.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, this question was recently posed to the cast and crew. Results were mixed, with most saying they never thought about it or saying as a droid BB-8 was genderless. JJ Abrahams stated

> I always refer to him as a 'he'. But I don't know, I haven't looked under the hood.

You can watch this segment here: