# What is BB-8's power source?

Tags: star-wars, bb-8

In Episodes VII and VIII we see BB-8, Poe Dameron's droid, be quite active, [follow our heroes around](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112553/why-does-bb-8-follow-rey), [climb stairs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112202/how-does-bb-8-climb-stairs), [move very quickly in the sand](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113600/how-does-bb-8-move-in-the-sand-without-skidding) etc, but as far as I remember we never see it ([him/her](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111825/is-bb-8-female)?) actually recharge.

So my question is: **What is BB-8's power source?**

Comment: The tears of fanbois

Comment: Are we going for a general target on this one? I see a bounty was given on the other one so if a bit more complete answer is given I agree.

Comment: @Valorum is there an echo in here?