# Does C-3PO golden shell consist of his original parts?

Tags: star-wars, droids, c-3po

Since there is obviously a backstory for everything in Star Wars, here is a very special question that has been on my mind for a while now.

At the beginning of his "life" C-3PO is "naked", his outer shell is added a little later.
But these parts are old and dirty.

Later in his "life" C-3PO has a golden shell.
Does his golden shell consist of his original parts that were painted golden or cleaned or are they completely different parts? Is there a story about that?

Is there a story about his silver leg?

I know there is a comic that explains his red arm from Episode VII.

Comment: He gets "shined" for this appearance on the stage at the end of ANH

Comment: The question of his silver leg is addressed here; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/963/why-does-c-3po-have-a-silver-lower-leg

Comment: It was sometime between AotC and The Clone Wars that he was given gold

Comment: Just watching ANH, one would naturally assume that, being a protocol droid for the royal household of Alderaan, the House of Alderaan majordomo would have ticked the "special gold furnishing" box on the ordering form, and possibly "add a specially padded box made from real Coruscant oak for transport", too. But Lucas had to mess everything up into an improbable hairball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will provide a *Legends* answer that was provided in the real world gap between Episode II and III.

If you watch **The Clone Wars microseries**, The golden shell is first shown in Chapter 21 of the said series, Anakin was walking down Coruscant streets, thought that he was followed only to find out that his follower was Padmé, a hooded C-3PO was there too calling for her, he is grabbed by Anakin and after a conversation about his outfit C-3PO says, *"In the service of a Senator one must be presentable"* to which Anakin says his *Impressive, Most Impressive* quote.

**BUT** Episode III novelization seems to describe Anakin giving Threepio the gold plating shortly after his wedding to Padmé.

So there was a continuity issue even back then.